# android vpn private package

Tags: android, vpn

Hi I got a private package to include android.net.vpn to change vpn settings programmatically. The android class path container has an android.jar file and i tried to add the newly downloaded jar file to the project but I was not able to compile the project. 
Then I removed the android.jar from the platform folder and copied my newly downloaded jar file to the platform folder. I got so many erors and I had to include quite a few jar file including jre System library to resolve the issues but I am stuck up with so many "No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_height' in package 'android'" error which i am not able to solve.

I believe that I am making a blunder with all this jar inclusion which i should not do. I want android.net.vpn to be available for my project. Please help how i should go about it.

Thanks

Comment: What are all the other packages you are including?

Comment: jre system library, httpmime,httpclient,httpcore. After i added all these the errors went off. But I did not have to include any of these with the android.jar that came with the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

This multi-part tutorial will show you how to use hidden or internal APIs in your project. It's a bit long but a very interesting (and useful) read. This will enable android.net.vpn

https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Comment: I made a simple script that pretty much boils all the points down to just a few steps - its all on the page mentioned and it really works!